# What's the difference between 'left out' and 'missed out'?

Tags: collocation

There is a sentence:
 *Negative comments were left out.*

Can I say:
*Negative comments were missed out.*  ?

What is general different between *miss out* and *left out* ?

I'm not sure which tags I should include. Is *collocation* OK?

Comment: Hi Jakub. What did you find when you looked up the two expressions in a dictionary? If you can explain what you found and what your remaining uncertainty is, it will help us to provide an answer for you. For further guidance, see [ask]. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **[Leave out](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/leave-out-something-someone)** means to fail to include something or someone; omit.
- **[Miss out](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/miss-out)** means to fail to
  use an opportunity to enjoy or get an advantage from something.

If you say:

> Negative comments
>   were **missed out**.

That means that someone lost an opportunity to give negative comments.

And if you say:

> Negative comments
>   were **left out**.

That means that someone **failed** to include those negative comments somewhere else.

Comment: ["lines were left out"](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&ei=-hfHW4SIBYO5zwLkoYnQAg&q=%22lines+were+left+out%22&oq=%22lines+were+left+out%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...135238.138412.0.139251.11.11.0.0.0.0.179.1445.0j10.10.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.4.610...0i8i7i30k1j0i7i30k1j0i30k1j0i8i30k1.0.n1Z4vYzmLbg) over 50,000 hits on Google

Comment: ["lines were missed out"](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&ei=-hfHW4SIBYO5zwLkoYnQAg&q=%22lines+were+missed+out%22&oq=%22lines+were+missed+out%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3412.11964.0.12697.23.23.0.0.0.0.204.3563.0j22j1.23.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.8.1274...0i8i7i30k1j0i7i30k1j0i30k1j0i8i30k1j33i10k1.0.5Uog6I9lRhs) 5 hits... P.S the word "accidentality" is pretty much non-existant.

Answer (score 2):

> Negative comments were *left out*.

Those comments were not included at reproduction of the material (for any reason, maybe *intentionally*).

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/leave-out

> Negative comments were *missed out*.

Accidentally, those comments were (appeared to be) not included.

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/miss-out

Comment: I shouldn't have upvoted, I read your answer too quickly.

Answer (score 0):

*Were left out* is correct.
**Were missed out* is ungrammatical. That's what the asterisk means.

The phrasal verb *leave out* 'omit' is transitive, and therefore can occur in the Passive construction.

- *They left out the book's index.*
- *The book's index was left out.*

The phrasal verb *miss out* 'lose (an opportunity)' is intransitive, and requires a transitivizing preposition *on* when it indicates the opportunity that was missed.

- **They missed out the party.*
- *They missed out on the party.*

Since it's intransitive, *miss out* can't be used in the Passive.

- **The party was missed out*.

The example sentence given,

> *Negative comments were missed out.*

is ungrammatical because *negative comments* is not an opportunity (so *missed out* should not be used at all); and also because *miss out* can't be used in the Passive.

Comment: -1: Google gives plenty of hits for "were missed out" including sites (in a tour), fences (in a race) and achievements (in a list).